# Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:: nested asn1 error with apn_on_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications

I am [trying to configure](http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-send-iphone-push-notifications-in-rail) [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails) to send push notifications from rails3 to iOS devices.

When I run `bundle exec rake apn:notifications:deliver --trace`
 I get the following error:

```
(in /home/mari/Documents/descuentos)
** Invoke apn:notifications:deliver (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute apn:notifications:deliver
rake aborted!
Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:: nested asn1 error
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bundler/gems/apn_on_rails-18f5d37397e3/lib/apn_on_rails/libs/connection.rb:52:in `initialize'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bundler/gems/apn_on_rails-18f5d37397e3/lib/apn_on_rails/libs/connection.rb:52:in `new'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bundler/gems/apn_on_rails-18f5d37397e3/lib/apn_on_rails/libs/connection.rb:52:in `open'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bundler/gems/apn_on_rails-18f5d37397e3/lib/apn_on_rails/libs/connection.rb:23:in `open_for_delivery'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bundler/gems/apn_on_rails-18f5d37397e3/lib/apn_on_rails/app/models/apn/notification.rb:104:in `send_notifications'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bundler/gems/apn_on_rails-18f5d37397e3/lib/apn_on_rails/tasks/apn.rake:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/mari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => apn:notifications:deliver
```

I am running the application from ubuntu (can that cause the problem?). The person that is an agent in the apple developers program has generated the p12 and the pem twice for me from his computer following these instructions:

> 1. Click the disclosure arrow next to your certificate in Keychain Access and select the certificate and the key.
> 2. Right click and choose `Export 2 items…`.
> 3. Choose the p12 format from the drop down and name it `cert.p12`.

but I keep getting the error.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate that was given to me was wrong. After generating the right certificate and p12 the problem was solved.